# Issue with position of data while displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach-loop-container

I have 2 tables named authors & books. Authors must have a logo. I have to display this like author name , logo,then all the books of that author and so on. books table contain a field (show_logo), if the show_logo is 0 for all the books of that author then the logo will display at the begining (ie after author name) else logo will display after that book(show_logo 1). If the show_logo is 1 for any book then it will display properly after that book, Otherwise won't..am using the code below

```
<?php
if ($author) {
    foreach ($$author as $key => $val) {
?>
        <tr style="background-color: #58353C;"><?php
        if ($val['$author_image']) {
?>
            <td><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>uploads/<?= $author; ?>" style="width: 90px;height: 90px;"/></td>
            <td style="color: #F5E78F;" colspan="4"><b><?= $val['$author_name']; ?></td>
    <?
            foreach ($val['books'] as $key => $val1) {
    ?>
            <tr style="background-color:<?= $color ?>">
    <?php
                if ($val1['author_image']) {
    ?>
                    <td style="padding-left: 20px;color: black; "><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>uploads/<?= $val1['author_image']; ?>" style="width: 75px;height: 75px;" /></td>
    <?php } ?>
                <td style="color: black;"><?= $val1['author_title']; ?></td>
                <td width="150px" style="text-align: left;color: black;"><a class="more" style="color: black;font-size: 11px;" href="<?= site_url('author/author_view/' . $key); ?>" rel="facebox">More Details..</a></td>
    <?
                if ($val1['show_logo'] == '1') {
                    if ($val['author_logo']) {
    ?></tr>
                    <tr style="background-color:<?= $color; ?>" on>
                        <td colspan="5"><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>uploads/<?= $val['author_logo']; ?>" style="width: 998px;height: 175px;" /></td>
                    </tr>                                                                                                                                            
<?
                    }
                } else {
?></tr> <?
                }
                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Tip: dont use shortcode `<?` and please make a (fiddle)[ http://jsfiddle.net] to understand better

Comment: could you edit your code so to go away with the braces since your escaping your php anyway

Comment: What does the `on` mean in this line `<tr style="background-color:<?= $color; ?>" on>`? Also, you have 2 `$` next to author in your foreach loop.

Comment: Also, can you explain what your issue is? You have some code posted so where exactly do you get stuck or what are you expecting that you don't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use the [HTML Table Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html) that CodeIgniter 2.x includes in default package? Just pre-format you arrays to reach proper structure.